How to access userId from Claim in .NET
I have and enpoint:
 [HttpGet("DecodeToken")]
    public void DecodeToken()
    {
        string? userIdFromClaim = User.FindFirst("userId")?.Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIdFromClaim))
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot get JWT token from claim");
        }
        int userId = int.TryParse(userIdFromClaim, out int parsedUserId) ? parsedUserId : throw new Exception("Cannot convert");
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded user id is + " + userId);
    }

and the i postman i send a request:
GET http://localhost:5235/Auth/DecodeToken

Authorization Bearer Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMyIsIm5iZiI6MTcxNTUyNTc3NywiZXhwIjoxNzE1NjEyMTc3LCJpYXQiOjE3MTU1MjU3Nzd9.kxl8uFYaB_8562PomDTNRcLhgtNv7dy7X640b8FRDYZXl4J2NALXlzs3pO5yIYw5Pb2X1i9SB5kB-IdK2PkQ4w

which is valid token, and i get:
  throw new Exception("Cannot get JWT token from claim");

Why? How to access this token?

Are you sure userId has been included to the claims list?

What do you use for your Authentication scheme?

You can/should verify your bearer token through jwt.io and see if the claim is present

You have to use [Authorize] attribute on controller or specific action. Otherwise, the authentication won't be performed so your User will be null.
If you use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package, then this should work:
[HttpGet("DecodeToken")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public void DecodeToken()
    {
        string? userIdFromClaim = User.FindFirst("userId")?.Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIdFromClaim))
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot get JWT token from claim");
        }
        int userId = int.TryParse(userIdFromClaim, out int parsedUserId) ? parsedUserId : throw new Exception("Cannot convert");
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded user id is + " + userId);
    }

If you have set global authorization policy that forces every request to be authenticated, then check which authentication scheme have you specified.

"You have to use [Authorize] attribute on controller or specific action. Otherwise, the authentication won't be performed so your User will be null." That's not true. It could be set at the controller level, or as the default/fallback policy.

thanks sir for your answer! but now everything is AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged...

What do you mean by everything? If you applied [Authorize] attribute, then it should challenge the Bearer scheme only on all routes that controller handles, or specific action (method within controller). Can you show your Program.cs or Startup.cs?
